# valid user input which begins with nine digits and ends with x or v

Tags: javascript, regex

```
                       regex = /^[0-9-+]+$/
```

i write above Regex for valid only nine numbers.but i want to valid number which ends with x or v.That means every user input should have x or v at the end of the input.i tried the following code to achieve that.It only valid  weather the input begins with 9 digits.

```
           var flag = regex.test(nic) && nic.length == 10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test for

```
regex = /^[0-9]{9}[xv]$/
```

`[0-9]{9}` checks for 9 digits at the start of the string
[xv] test for the end character

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex:

```
 /^[+-]?[0-9]{9}[xv]$/
```

`[+-]?`: Means optional sign

`[0-9]{9}`: Means 9 digits

`[xv]`: Means one of the 'x' or 'v'

Answer (score 1):

Regex should read the following:

/^[0-9]{9}[xv]$/